# Why is importing and running opencv contrib showing error even though I have python3 installed?

Tags: python, opencv

I have written this python code after importing opencv contrib:

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
while True:
 _, frame = cap.read()
 cv2.imshow('cam star', frame)
 if cv2.waitKey(10) == ord('q'):
     break
```

When I run this in VS Code, I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/python3 "/Users/namanbansal/Documents/python projects/selfie.py"
namanbansal@Namans-MacBook-Air python projects % /usr/bin/python3 
"/Users/namanbansal/Documents/python projects/selfie.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/namanbansal/Documents/python projects/selfie.py", line 1, in <module>
import cv2
File "/Users/namanbansal/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site- 
packages/cv2/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
from .cv2 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/namanbansal/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site- 
packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: 
/opt/homebrew/opt/tesseract/lib/libtesseract.4.dylib
Referenced from: /Users/namanbansal/Library/Python/3.8/lib/python/site- 
packages/cv2/cv2.cpython-38-darwin.so
Reason: image not found
```

I did the install by typing in 'pip3 install opencv-contrib-python' in the vs code terminal.
Please guide how to fix this! I am a beginner. I'm on a mac for further details.

Comment: Are your opencv and opencv-contrib of same version ?

Comment: Try running this from the command line instead of in VS Code.  You sometimes can get aberrant behavior inside the IDE debugger.

Comment: it's missing lib`tesseract`. **how** did you install opencv? provide all information that could be useful.

Comment: I just typed in 'pip3 install opencv-contrib-python'